# The named parameter 'body' isn't defined. in flutter code

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I'm practising this code [github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4wdb.png) to add a home screen with cards as pictures shown below. after the get started button clicks it should redirect to the home page with cards. cards are not still designed like the picture shows. the code I used to get cards is not working. can someone know how to fix this? no errors on main. dart.  error is in home_page.dart. think I'm missing some codes.
error shows ----> Missing concrete implementation of 'StatefulWidget.createState'.

> home_page.dart

```
         import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
            import 'package:fashion_app/color_filters.dart';
            
         class HomePage extends StatefulWidget{
              @override
                _HomePageState createSatate ()=> _HomePageState();
              }
            
            
            class _HomePageState extends State <HomePage> {
              final double _borderRadious = 24;
            
              Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                return Scaffold(
                    appBar: AppBar(
                      title: Text('Fashion store'),
),
                      body: ListView(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                        children: [
                          buildQuoteCard(),
                          buildRoundedCard(),
                          buildColoredCard(),
                          buildImageCard(),
                          buildImageInteractionCard(),
                        ],
                      ),
            
                    )
                );
              }
            
              Widget buildQuoteCard() =>
                  Card(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            'If life were predictable it would cease to be life, 
    and be without flavor.',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 12),
                          Text(
                            'Eleanor Roosevelt',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
            
              Widget buildRoundedCard() =>
                  Card(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                    ),
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            'Rounded card',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 4),
                          Text(
                            'This card is rounded',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
            
              Widget buildColoredCard() =>
                  Card(
                    shadowColor: Colors.red,
                    elevation: 8,
                    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
                    ),
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                          colors: [Colors.redAccent, Colors.red],
                          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        ),
                      ),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            'Colored card',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 4),
                          Text(
                            'This card is rounded and has a gradient',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
            
              Widget buildImageCard() =>
                  Card(
                    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
                    ),
                    child: Stack(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Ink.image(
                          image: NetworkImage(
                            'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1514888286974-6c03e2ca1dba?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1327&q=80',
                          ),
                          colorFilter: ColorFilters.greyscale,
                          child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {},
                          ),
                          height: 240,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Card With Splash',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 24,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
            
              Widget buildImageInteractionCard() =>
                  Card(
                    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Stack(
                          children: [
                            Ink.image(
                              image: NetworkImage(
                                'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1514888286974-6c03e2ca1dba?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1327&q=80',
                              ),
                              height: 240,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                            Positioned(
                              bottom: 16,
                              right: 16,
                              left: 16,
                              child: Text(
                                'Cats rule the world!',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 24,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16).copyWith(bottom: 0),
                          child: Text(
                            'The cat is the only domesticated species in the family Felidae and is often referred to as the domestic cat to distinguish it from the wild members of the family.',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                        ),
                        ButtonBar(
                          alignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            FlatButton(
                              child: Text('Buy Cat'),
                              onPressed: () {},
                            ),
                            FlatButton(
                              child: Text('Buy Cat Food'),
                              onPressed: () {},
                            )
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
            
            
            }
    
    > main. dart
    
      
    
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    import 'constants.dart';
    import 'home_page.dart';
    
    void main() => runApp(MyApp());
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Auth Screen 1',
          theme: ThemeData(
            brightness: Brightness.light,
            primaryColor: kPrimaryColor,
            scaffoldBackgroundColor: kBackgroundColor,
    
            textTheme: TextTheme(
              headline4: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              button: TextStyle(color: kPrimaryColor),
              headline6: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
            ),
            inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
              enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(.2),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          home: WelcomeScreen(),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class WelcomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Color(0XFFd5ae48),
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*.4,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage("assets/images/girl.png"),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                flex: 3,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    RichText(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      text: TextSpan(
                        children: [
                          TextSpan(
                            text: "Let Your Styles Speaks\n",
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
    
                          ),
                          TextSpan(
                            text: "Discover the latest trends in women fashion and explore your personality\n",
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    FittedBox(
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) {
                              return HomePage();
                            },
                          ));
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 25),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 26, vertical: 16),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                          child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(
                                "Get started",
                                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button?.copyWith(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 20
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: 10),
                              Icon(
                                Icons.arrow_forward,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: The error is telling you createState() hasn't been implemented. Check your spelling (createSatate) and it should work fine.

Comment: it's done. now when click the get started button, It display red and Unimplemented error

Answer (score 1):

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget/createState.html

Change this,

```
 class HomePage extends StatefulWidget{
              @override
                _HomePageState createSatate ()=> _HomePageState(); // change createSatate to createState
              }
```

To,

```
 class HomePage extends StatefulWidget{
              @override
                _HomePageState createState ()=> _HomePageState();
              }
```

Comment: still display as unimplemented error

Comment: Update your latest  code.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XmO_gQNLsdQEaBhFTNhZlj8OdIwjQUkGo31uPLcCaew/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Flutter clean and then Rerun your code.

Comment: wow, it's worked. thank you so much.

Comment: I also want to add a product detail page to this. how can I add navigation to that from a card?

Answer (score 1):

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _HomePageState createSatate ()=> _HomePageState();
}
```

It's because of a typo.

Change `createSatate` to `createState`.

Your Homepage class will look like

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _HomePageState createState ()=> _HomePageState();
}
```

Comment: thank you so much